# Electron - How can I understand when an application runs on Mac OS, is it related to the file type or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, macos, electron

I am creating a **Mac OS** application on **Electron**.

My ***application*** is ***associated*** with certain types of **files**. Another application may switch the association to itself. While the application is running, i need to check whether the application is associated with files. If the application is not associated with a file, notify the user about this.

Please tell me how this can be done by means of **NodeJS** and/or **Electron**?

```
{
   "appId": "com.example.app",
   "files": ["build", "static", "index.js"],
   "fileAssociations": [
        {
            "ext": ["txt", "md", "yml"],
            "name": "Plain Text",
            "role": "Editor"
        }
    ],
    "mac": {
        "target": [
            {
                "target": "dmg",
                "arch": [
                    "x64"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If use

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/Current/Support/lsregister -dump
```

You can get information about file associations with applications.

For example, in my case, I received from a dump:

```
  { 'type id': ' ',
    'claim id': 'Plain Text (UTF-16) (0x1258)',
    uti: ' ',
    flags:
     'apple-internal  doc-type  resolves-icloud-conflicts (0000000000000222)',
    'conforms to': ' ',
    tags: ' ',
    rank: 'Default',
    bundle: 'System Information (0x31c)',
    roles: 'None (0000000000000001)',
    bindings: '.txt' },
    
  { 'type id': 'public.plain-text (0x150c)',
    'claim id': ' ',
    uti: 'public.plain-text',
    flags:
     'active  public  apple-internal  exported  core  trusted (0000000000000077)',
    'conforms to': 'public.text',
    tags: '.txt, .text, text/plain',
    rank: ' ',
    bundle: 'CoreTypes (0x21c)',
    roles: ' ',
    bindings: ' ' },
    
  { 'type id': ' ',
    'claim id': '6008 (0x1778)',
    uti: ' ',
    flags: 'doc-type (0000000000000020)',
    'conforms to': ' ',
    tags: ' ',
    rank: 'Default',
    bundle: 'Sublime Text (0x614)',
    roles: 'Editor (0000000000000004)',
    bindings: '.txt' },
    
  { 'type id': ' ',
    'claim id': 'Visual Studio Code document (0x16a0)',
    uti: ' ',
    flags:
     'relative-icon-path  legacy-wildcard  doc-type (0000000000000034)',
    'conforms to': ' ',
    tags: ' ',
    rank: 'Default',
    bundle: 'Code (0x600)',
    roles: 'Editor (0000000000000004)',
    bindings:
     '.clj, .cljs, .cljx, .clojure, .code-workspace, .coffee, .ctp, .dockerfile, .dot, .edn, .fs, .fsi, .fsscript, .fsx, .handlebars, .hbs, .lua, .m, .makefile, .ml, .mli, .pl, .pl6, .pm, .pm6, .pod, .pp, .properties, .psgi, .pug, .r, .rs, .rt, .svg, .svgz, .t, .txt, .vb, .xcodeproj, .xcworkspace, \'TEXT\', \'utxt\', \'TUTX\', \'****\'' }
```

How do I know if my application will start when I double-click on a file?

Comment: According to [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/20822/where-does-mac-os-x-store-file-association-information), you can use `defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices | grep -v LSBundleLocator` and/or `lsregister -dump`. You would use `child_process.exec` to run them from node and get their output.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. I am new to Mac OS. Maybe this works, but in some cases the Mac OS com.apple.LaunchServices is missing. In my case, it is not in the libraries.

Comment: Hm I see, some of these answers are old. But `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/Current/Support/lsregister -dump` still works for me

Comment: The `com.apple.LaunchServices` default domain will only exist if there is any custom association at all. Otherwise only the system defaults (that `lsregister` _does_ list) exist. But you asked what if another application changes the association, and in that case it's already custom.

Comment: Your path
 **/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/Current/Support/lsregister -dump** 

works. But is it always correct?

Comment: Perhaps I did not use the command correctly, do not tell me the correct option?`admin@Admins-Mac Support % sudo defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices | grep -v LSBundleLocator 
Password:
2020-06-19 08:54:56.136 defaults[26161:1231837] 
Domain com.apple.LaunchServices does not exist
admin@Admins-Mac Support %`

Comment: As I said I think the issue here is just that no _custom_ associations exist yet. But I'm not super skilled in Mac so I may be missing something.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Unfortunately, even this is not correct: **"lsregister -dump. You would use child_process.exec to run them from node and get their output."**.

Because of: **RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded**.

Comment: That would just mean that the output is longer than the buffer, so you could redirect it to a file or use `spawn` instead of `exec` and attach a listener to the `stdout` stream, storing the data in chunks.

Comment: Yes, you are right perhaps to try chunks.

Comment: The construction of **"const child = spawn ('cd /;', [execLine, argument], {shell: true});"** works. I do not like it. But unfortunately I have not yet found other ways.